# Getting error when using FILTERING in a Window on top command

Tags: terminal, top, macos

Trying to filter results of [top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) command by **Filtering in a Window**, pressing `o` then typing filter, like described in a tutorial here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html

but when I typing for example `COMMAND=iTerm2` or any other command I get `invalid order` error.

You can see animated gif with an issue here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhhtl.jpg

- OS: Mac OS Catalina version: 10.15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`o` isn't a filter on [BSD top](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?top(1)), it's a sort.

```
     o       Change the order in which the display is sorted.  The sort key
     names include cpu, res, size, time.  The default is cpu.
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to filter it the way you want.

So you could press `o` then type `COMMAND` but `COMMAND=iTerm2` is invalid.

Alternatively you could run `top` with the `-pid` option to filter out a single pid but it's likely that iTerm2 is running more than one process.

```
top -pid $(pgrep iTerm2 | head -1)
```

Comment: I apologize but tutorial says total different things: 
` o | O  :Other-Filtering You will be prompted for the selection criteria which then
              determines which tasks will be shown in the `current' window.
              Your criteria can be made case sensitive or case can be
              ignored.  And you determine if top should include or exclude
              matching tasks. `

Comment: @Anatoly: it's not a tutorial, it's a man page.  And it's a man page for software that you are not using.  Since you are on macos you are using BSD top.

Comment: Now it makes sense, can you please mention this in answer, so I will be able to accept it, please?

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac Terminal Zsh the top command has many differences with traditional linux implementations, as exemplified with the OP's question. I found a nice solution for filtering all iTerm2 processes:

```
top -pid $(pgrep -d " -pid " iTerm2)
```

The list of pids are returned with a `-pid` flag as a separator. The first `-pid` flag covers the bare initial pid.

---

Edit: I wanted to make it a little easier for myself to utilize this approach, so I created a zsh function `topg`. I welcome any feedback on my shell scripting. It is essentially a wrapper around top that adds the flags [-g|--grep]. I'll post updates as I refine it.

As for usage, you can either pass string of different process names separated by a space or append several flags together. Any other commands that top would respond to are passed through.

*Example Usage:*

`topg -g ssh --grep firefox -g "WindowServer Gitify"`

```
function topg () {
    emulate -L zsh
    zmodload zsh/zutil || return

    # Default option values can be specified as (value).
    local help filter_commands

    zparseopts -D -F -K -a -- \
        {h,-help}=help    \
        {g,-grep}+:=filter_commands || return

    if (( $#help )); then
        local top_help=`top -h`
        local lines
        lines=( ${(f)top_help} )
        lines[1]=${lines[1]:gs/top/tops}
        lines[3]=(${lines[3]}, "$(echo "\t\t")[-g <pattern> [<pattern2>] | --grep <pattern> [<pattern2>]]")

        print -rC1 -- \
        ${(F)lines}
        return
    fi

    if (( $#filter_commands )); then
        local -a array
        local flag vals

        for flag vals in "${(@)filter_commands}"; do
            array+=(${=vals})
        done

        eval "top -pid $(pgrep -d " -pid " "${(@)array}") "${@:1}""
        return
    else
        eval "top "${@:1}""
        return
    fi

}
```

Like I said, I welcome any feedback.